# using browser local storage in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova, local-storage

I'm creating a mobile application (For IOS, Android) and I first develop it in my browser. I need to use the local storage. I understand that local storage is working for a specific domain (A bit like cookies). The thing is that now when I'm working on the development server I have a domain and local storage is working correctly. What i'm a bit worried is that when I move to Phonegap and run the files locally I might not have access to local storage as there is no domain (a bit like not having cookies when you develop on an IP instead of a domain).

I know that phonegap has it's own storage but I rather not use it now as it's web sql based which is depricated as far as I understood by researching).

So, if the HTML files are local in the Phonegap webview application (not opened from a remote server, but stored locally) can I still use the local storage?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage works just fine in a PhoneGap/Cordova app.

Comment: OK, just making sure I got this correct - so it doesn't matter if there is no domain (files opened locally).

Comment: It shouldn't for LocalStorage, nope.